# Video call causing mobile data connection to go off

Tags: javascript, webrtc

**Update:**

It seems the issue is with ISP. When I used other ISP(SIM) it worked on the same phone. Using the previous SIM on other phone caused the same issue there. That means something is happening at ISP's end. What is left there to try after I already have a TURN server set up?

```
const RTCconfiguration = {
sdpSemantics: "unified-plan",
iceServers: [
        {
            urls: "turn:numb.viagenie.ca",
            username: "username-goes-here",
            credential: "password-goes-here" 
        }, 
        {
            urls:  ["stun:stun.voipbuster.com"]
            
            
        }
    ]
 }

 myPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(RTCconfiguration);
```

**Original post:**

I have posted a question about the call issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63279773/webrtc-video-causes-the-call-top-drop-over-internet). But now I am not sure what is this new issue about.

During video call to mobile network (tested only one ISP) the data connection icon in the status bar of mobile disappears as if data was turned off and then soon the call drops as well. Then the data network icon returns to the status bar. This issue is also noticed by my friend ( same ISP).

I tried to Google for the issue but I didn't get anything like this.

I am not sure what code would be relevant here so I am not posting it.

The data connection turns off temporarily at `await myPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);` or `await myPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);` call in my code

I have added STUN and TURN servers to my code. The problem isn't fixed.
I tried video calling with cell data at [zipcall.io](https://zipcall.io) The problem appears there too.

My friend connected his second phone to Wi-Fi (from the first phone's cell data) and I did same on my side. We were able to have the call last for about 7 minutes.

But using cell data on either side makes the data connection go off and then come back. That is, the original issue that I posted.